# Как проинициализировать массив std?

Tags: c++

Есть двумерный массив

```
std::array<std::array<char, 50>, 50> map{};
```

Как проинициализировать его массивами, которые имеют значение

```
#define EMPTY_CELL 'e'
```

Краткое решение для такого есть? Неужели цикл нужно писать и присваивать?

Answer (score 1):

Именно проинициализировать нельзя, насколько я знаю. Самый простой вариант такой:

```
std::array<std::array<char, 50>, 50> map;
for (auto &it : map)
    it.fill(EMPTY_CELL);
```

---

Ну и, советвую не использовать макросы по пустякам: `constexpr char empty_cell = 'e';`.

Comment: да тут даже обычно const хватит, "не нужно использовать его по пустякам":) дольше писать:)))